# What is the difference between "length" and "size" of a sequence?

Tags: c++

I'm currently doing c++ stack problems and I am having trouble understanding the meaning of these two instructions. Can someone help explain to me what the difference length and size is in this context?

1. **Read in a sequence of positive integers from the keyboard, one per line, and terminated by any negative integer;**
2. **Output a blank line, followed by a line with the length of the sequence, followed by a line with the sum of the values in the sequence, followed by another blank line; To determine the size of the sequence you must use the stack size function;**

Here's what I think it means:

2 // one sequence?

3 // second sequence?

4 // third sequence?

length of sequence: 3?

Sum: 9

Stack Size: 3??? // isn't stack size just the size of sequence? confused?

Comment: 1) **Why don't you ask to whoever gave you this assignment?** 2) Why do you print "Stack Size"? The assignment simply asks to print the length of the sequence and the sum. 3) `2, 3, 4` is **one** sequence of integers. And, as the assignment tells, you must also input a negative number to terminate it. 4) To me it's simply asking you to use `std::stack::size` (although nowhere else it's implied that you have to use that data structure).

Comment: Sounds to me like you're over-thinking this. Read the numbers into a container. Print out the number of items in the container, followed by the sum of the items in the container. That's it.

Comment: There is no difference between the size of a sequence and the length of a sequence, they're two different words for the same thing, so you can stop worrying about that detail.

Comment: Seems I was overthinking it.. thanks for inputs guys!

Comment: In general size==length. Though unless it's a sequence, we don't speak of length at all. Naturally, there are exceptions, like c-strings, where the terminator counts for the size but not for the length ;-) That's what makes programming *interesting*.

Comment: Usually, *size* is related to *allocated* memory, and *length* (or *count*) is related to *used* data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, you're supposed to read integers into `std::stack<int>` in a `for` (or `while` or `do`-`while`) loop terminating with a negative input. Then you shall print to stdout the length=size of the sequence (the number of elements) as given by `std::stack::size()` and next the sum, which you may also compute using some `std` functionality.

I think the assignment is pretty clear, but perhaps your ability of reading & understanding plain English could be improved?

Comment: OHh crap, I misread it, I thought it wanted me to print it twice but I guess not.

Comment: @bolov I didn't mean to be offensive, but there must be some reason.

Comment: well I remember when I was (younger - but don't tell anybody) completely new to a thing and was questioning even my basic knowledge because I was afraid to do something wrong. I mean, sure it is obvious that X, but I what if there is some fact that I don't know making X not true...

Answer (score 0):

Based on how I understand the assignment, **size** is used to mean **length**.

The length of a C++ container is the number of elements, not its storage capacity.